# Consuming on multiple topics with pika and TornadoConnection

Tags: python, rabbitmq, tornado, pika

I have a class for a pika consumer client that's based on pika's example code for the TornadoConnection. I'm trying to consume from a topic queue. The problem is that since the connection is established in an asynchronous way, there is no way for me to know when the channel is established or when the queue is declared. My class:

```
class PikaClient(object):
    """ Based on:
    http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/tornado_consumer.html
    https://reminiscential.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/realtime-notification-delivery-using-rabbitmq-tornado-and-websocket/
    """

    def __init__(self, exchange, exchange_type):
        self._connection = None
        self._channel = None
        self._closing = False
        self._consumer_tag = None

        self.exchange = exchange
        self.exchange_type = exchange_type
        self.queue = None

        self.event_listeners = set([])

    def connect(self):
        logger.info('Connecting to RabbitMQ')

        cred = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
        param = pika.ConnectionParameters(
            host='localhost',
            port=5672,
            virtual_host='/',
            credentials=cred,
        )

        return pika.adapters.TornadoConnection(param,
            on_open_callback=self.on_connection_open)

    def close_connection(self):
        logger.info('Closing connection')
        self._connection.close()

    def on_connection_closed(self, connection, reply_code, reply_text):
        self._channel = None
        if not self._closing:
            logger.warning('Connection closed, reopening in 5 seconds: (%s) %s',
                           reply_code, reply_text)
            self._connection.add_timeout(5, self.reconnect)

    def on_connection_open(self, connection):
        logger.info('Connected to RabbitMQ')
        self._connection.add_on_close_callback(self.on_connection_closed)
        self._connection.channel(self.on_channel_open)

    def reconnect(self):
        if not self._closing:
            # Create a new connection
            self._connection = self.connect()

    def on_channel_closed(self, channel, reply_code, reply_text):
        logger.warning('Channel %i was closed: (%s) %s',
                       channel, reply_code, reply_text)
        self._connection.close()

    def on_channel_open(self, channel):
        logger.info('Channel open, declaring exchange')
        self._channel = channel
        self._channel.add_on_close_callback(self.on_channel_closed)
        self._channel.exchange_declare(self.on_exchange_declareok,
                                       self.exchange,
                                       self.exchange_type,
                                       passive=True,
                                       )

    def on_exchange_declareok(self, unused_frame):
        logger.info('Exchange declared, declaring queue')
        self._channel.queue_declare(self.on_queue_declareok,
                                   exclusive=True,
                                   auto_delete=True,
                                   )

    def on_queue_declareok(self, method_frame):
        self.queue = method_frame.method.queue

    def bind_key(self, routing_key):
        logger.info('Binding %s to %s with %s',
                    self.exchange, self.queue, routing_key)
        self._channel.queue_bind(self.on_bindok, self.queue,
                                 self.exchange, routing_key)

    def add_on_cancel_callback(self):
        logger.info('Adding consumer cancellation callback')
        self._channel.add_on_cancel_callback(self.on_consumer_cancelled)

    def on_consumer_cancelled(self, method_frame):
        logger.info('Consumer was cancelled remotely, shutting down: %r',
                    method_frame)
        if self._channel:
            self._channel.close()

    def on_message(self, unused_channel, basic_deliver, properties, body):
        logger.debug('Received message # %s from %s',
                    basic_deliver.delivery_tag, properties.app_id)
        #self.notify_listeners(body)

    def on_cancelok(self, unused_frame):
        logger.info('RabbitMQ acknowledged the cancellation of the consumer')
        self.close_channel()

    def stop_consuming(self):
        if self._channel:
            logger.info('Sending a Basic.Cancel RPC command to RabbitMQ')
            self._channel.basic_cancel(self.on_cancelok, self._consumer_tag)

    def start_consuming(self):
        logger.info('Issuing consumer related RPC commands')
        self.add_on_cancel_callback()
        self._consumer_tag = self._channel.basic_consume(self.on_message, no_ack=True)

    def on_bindok(self, unused_frame):
        logger.info('Queue bound')
        self.start_consuming()

    def close_channel(self):
        logger.info('Closing the channel')
        self._channel.close()

    def open_channel(self):
        logger.info('Creating a new channel')
        self._connection.channel(on_open_callback=self.on_channel_open)

    def run(self):
        self._connection = self.connect()

    def stop(self):
        logger.info('Stopping')
        self._closing = True
        self.stop_consuming()
        logger.info('Stopped')
```

An example for code using it (inside a WebSocketHandler.open):

```
self.pc = PikaClient('agents', 'topic')
self.pc.run()
self.pc.bind_key('mytopic.*')
```

When trying to run this, bind_key throws an exception because the _channel is still None. But I haven't found a way to block until the channel and queue are established. Is there any way to do this with a dynamic list of topics (that might change after the consumer starts running)?

Answer (score 0):

You actually do have a way to know when the queue is established - the method `on_queue_declareok()`. That callback will executed once the `self.queue_declare` method has finished, and `self.queue_declare` is executed once `_channel.exchance_declare` has finished, etc. You can follow the chain all the way back to your run method:

`run` -> `connect` -> `on_connection_open` -> `_connection.channel` -> `on_channel_open` -> `_channel.exchange_declare` -> `on_exchange_declareok` -> `_channel.queue_declare` -> `on_queue_declareok`

So, you just add your call(s) to `bind_key` to `on_queue_declareok`, and that will trigger a call to `on_bindok`, which will call `start_consuming`. At that point your client is actually listening for messages. If you want to be able to dynamically provide topics, just take them in the constructor of `PikaClient`. Then you can call `bind_key` on each inside `on_queue_declareok`. You'd also need to add a flag to indicate you've already started consuming, so you don't try to do that twice.

Something like this (assume all methods not shown below stay the same):

```
def __init__(self, exchange, exchange_type, topics=None):
    self._topics = [] if topics is None else topics
    self._connection = None
    self._channel = None
    self._closing = False
    self._consumer_tag = None
    self._consuming = False

    self.exchange = exchange
    self.exchange_type = exchange_type
    self.queue = None

    self.event_listeners = set([])

def on_queue_declareok(self, method_frame):
    self.queue = method_frame.method.queue
    for topic in self._topics:
        self.bind_key(topic)

def start_consuming(self):
    if self._consuming:
        return
    logger.info('Issuing consumer related RPC commands')
    self.add_on_cancel_callback()
    self._consumer_tag = self._channel.basic_consume(self.on_message, no_ack=True)
    self._consuming = True
```

Comment: How would you change the list of topics after initializing the client? I considered stopping the client and starting a new instance, but there's got to be a better way.